# Jquery CSS transform not working for get 5th value in cordova in android

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, css, cordova

The problem is :I build cordova android and run but, when i try to read the 5th value (the value in Y coordination axle) of code below :

```
$("piece.black").css("transform")
```

it get to me always "0", But it get 4th value truly but wen i try to read.

The point is that work good for X

In Other word, Why it get "0" in next line ?

```
alert($("piece.black").css("transform").match(/-?[\d\.]+/g)[5]);
```

but it is true for "[4]"

```
            alert($("piece.black").css("transform").match(/-?[\d\.]+/g)[4]);
```

It is working nicely in browser but not in cordova (android).
I test other version of JQuery but not work !!!

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <style type="text/css" >
        .pawn{
            background-color: red;
            width: 10%;
            min-width: 10%;
            position: absolute;
            padding-top: 10%;
            background-size: contain;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mainGame" style="background-color: #ccccff;width: 100%;padding-top: 100%;">
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#mainGame").append("<piece style='transform: translate(600%,500%);' class='pawn black'></piece>");
        alert($("#mainGame").width());
        alert($("piece.black").css("transform"));
        alert($("piece.black").css("transform").match(/-?[\d\.]+/g)[4]);
        alert($("piece.black").css("transform").match(/-?[\d\.]+/g)[5]);
    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: I found problem is cause of using "%",

Comment: Apparently some version of android work fine but not min !!!